# How to make array with => php (Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have my shopping cart with main logic in custom class:

```
public $items = NULL;
    public $totalQty = 0;
    public $totalPrice = 0;

    public function __construct($oldCart){
      if($oldCart){
        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
        $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
      }
    }
    public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

To place order I serialize this array and store in DB.

```
public function new_order_place(Request $request){

    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

    $order = new Order();
    $order->cart = serialize($cart);

      $order->name = $request->input('name')?$request->input('name'):Auth::user()->name;
      $order->email = $request->input('e-mail') ? $request->input('e-mail'):Auth::user()->email;
      $order->phone = $request->input('phone')?$request->input('phone'):(Auth::user()->phone?Auth::user()->phone:$this->validate($request, ['phone' => 'required']));
      $order->address = $request->input('address');

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();
    Session::forget('cart');
    return redirect()->route('index');
  }
```

Array looks like:

```
__PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
(
    [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => App\Classes\Cart
    [items] => Array
        (
            [4] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                    [id] => 4
                    [prod_url] => gorenje_g_5111_wf
                    [code_cat] => large-home-appliances
                    [url_cat] => cookers
                    [name] => Плита газовая GORENJE G 5111 WF
                    [cost] => 490
                    [price] => 490
                    [img] => img_16.jpg
                )

        )

    [totalQty] => 1
    [totalPrice] => 490
)
```

But also I have a modal with a Buy Now button where a user can buy a specific product without adding it to the cart. I am trying to create the same array because I cannot display orders in the user panel due to the different array structure.

```
public function modal_order_place(Request $request){


    $selprod['items'] = array(
      $request->id => array(
          'name' => $request->name,
          'qty' => $request->qty,
          'code' => $request->code,
          'img' => $request->img,
          'totalPrice' => $request->totalPrice
        )
      );


    $order = new Order();

    $order->cart = serialize($selprod);

    $order->name = $request->username;
    $order->email = $request->email;
    $order->phone = $request->phone;

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();

    return response()->json([
      'notif_text' => 'Your order has been accepted for processing! Expect a call!'
    ]);
  }
```

Laravel swears:
`Attempting to get the "items" property of a non-object`
If I delete the product added through the modal window, then everything is already working. The problem is in the array.

How is it possible to create the same array?

Answer (score 0):

You need another level of nesting.

```
$selprod['items'] = array(
    $request->id => array(
          'id' => $request->id,
          'name' => $request->name,
          'code' => $request->code,
          'img' => $request->img,
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I clarified the question a little, can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: In the edit you've got an object created by an API. You need to use that API to create new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. To fix this problem, you need to convert it to an object before serializing our array. From my code:

```
public function modal_order_place(Request $request){
    $selprod['items'] = array(
      $request->id => array(
          'name' => $request->name,
          'qty' => $request->qty,
          'code' => $request->code,
          'img' => $request->img,
          'totalPrice' => $request->totalPrice
        )
      );

    $object = (object)$selprod;//This line will convert our array to an object

    $order = new Order();

    $order->cart = serialize($object);//Here we are already serializing our object, not an array

    $order->name = $request->username;
    $order->email = $request->email;
    $order->phone = $request->phone;

    Auth::check()?Auth::user()->orders()->save($order):$order->save();

    return response()->json([
      'notif_text' => 'Your order has been accepted for processing! Expect a call!'
    ]);
  }
```

During deserialization, an array is obtained with the same structure as the basket creates and Laravel no longer swears:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => name
                    [qty] => 1
                    [img] => img_10.jpg
                    [cost] => 380
                )

        )

)
```